# Send a value from html to Routes in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I was wondering how I send a value from an html file to the routes.php file in laravel. This is my html:

```
<h1 id="title"  name="otherUser" value="{{session()->get('user2')}}">{{session()->get('user2')}}</h1>
```

And this is my php:

```
Route::post('commendUser', function(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();
    $username = /*FIXME*/ ;
    echo($username);
});
```

Can anyone explain how to properly get the username value from the html to Routes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get any value from your html using name attribute :

```
$username = $request->otherUser;

or :

$username = $request->input('otherUser');

or using a global helper:

$username = request('otherUser');

or using Input facade :

$username = Input::get('otherUser');
```

**however** You need to setup a form with a post method not `h1` tag for example:

```
<form action="/commendUser" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="otherUser" value="{{session()->get('user2')}}">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and in your route you can use `dd($username)` instead of echo it.

**Update**

You will need also to import the Request facade at the top of your `web.php` file like so:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('commendUser', function(Request $request) {
    dd($request->input('otherUser'));
});
```

## also

Any HTML forms pointing to `POST`, `PUT`, or `DELETE` routes that are defined in the web routes file should include a CSRF token field. Otherwise, the request will be rejected. You can read more about `CSRF` protection in the [CSRF documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf) so i have added it to the form:

## if

You still getting an empty value it's probably something wrong with the 
the session value.

Comment: Can you explain what the HTML would then look like? I am still a little bit confused...

Comment: I have updated my answer check it and tell me if something is unclear.

Comment: It says null when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using HTML tags properly, H1 is not a form field for sending data. Use  instead.